Connect SQL Developer to local Oracle DB 19c instance?
It's been a while since I've installed and connected to a fresh installation of Oracle DB 19c, so here goes. I also tried to find a solution on my own, but didn't find anything.
I installed Oracle DB 19c locally. Once installation's complete, I get message: Oracle Enterprise Manager Database Express URL: https:||localhost:5501/em
My Global Database Name is Oracle19CDemo and I selected a Virtual Account for login.
Question: how do I connect to the Oracle19CDemo DB with Oracle SQL Developer? And what username should I use?
I'm including the SQL Developer screenshot:


5501 is not the standard SQLNEt port, that the Oracle Listener is using to answer JDBC connection requests from tools like SQL Developer.
The default it 1521, try that.
5501 is for http(s)
HTTP <> JDBC
Also, in 19c, don't use SID, use the Service name option

Thanks for the post. Actually, this video helped alot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3r8shGn2mY

great to hear you're up and running now!
